# Dynamic search using Entity Framework word by word

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I'm new to Entity Framework. I need to search this word 'johnny' in text stored in the database. The text is from pdf files. So there are many words in the text columns.

Here is my code

```
using (var d = new DatabaseContext())
{
    var l = d.Pages.Where(x => x.Text.ToLower().Contains(text.ToLower())).ToList();
}
```

So far the code is working.

But the requirement changed. If the user types in `jhonny bravo`, the program will have to search for the word `jhonny` and `bravo` in the `Text` column. The `jhonny` and `bravo` should be found, even if the words in the `Text` column are:

```
Jhonny is bravo
jhonny is not bravo
```

How can I solve this?

I came up with the idea that split the text and search for each word

```
using (var d = new DatabaseContext())
{
    var split = Regex.Split(text, @"\s+");

    if (split.Count() > 1)
    {
        var l = d.Pages.Where(x => x.Text.ToLower().Contains(text.ToLower())).ToList();
    }
}
```

But using the code above. How can I create a dynamic search? What if the search term contains 6 words? How can I do the query? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create `Where` chain from `word` conditions:

```
using (var db = new DatabaseContext())
{
    var words = Regex.Split(text, @"\s+");
    var query = db.Pages.AsQuerable();
    foreach(var word in words)
        query = query.Where(x => x.Text.ToLower().Contains(word.ToLower()));
    var answer = query.ToList();
}
```

Comment: Why do you use `AsQueryable`? `dbContext.Pages` already implements `IQueryable<Page>`, doesn't it?

Comment: @HaraldCoppoolse, yes it is. But how are you going assign `IQueryable<Page>` to `IDbSet<Page>`? Only reverse is possible.

Comment: Do you really need `IDbSet`? Is that because you are using query syntax instead of method syntax? I always use method syntax, so I'm not really familiar with the ins and outs of query syntax. Using method syntax, I would think that since you are using only extension methods of IQueryable, that you wouldn't need IdbSet?

Answer (score 0):

Here I split the text on spaces, we then get a list of every word in the text.

I also use the method `Distinct()` to remove all the duplicated word, I'm not sure if there is any performance gain but if you don't like it you can remove it.

```
var keywords = ["john", "bravo", "hello"]
var l = d.Pages
         .Where(page => { 
                 var words = page.Text.ToLower().Split(' '). Distinct();

                 foreach(var keyword in keywords) {
                     if (!words.Contains(keyword.ToLower())
                        return false;
                 }

                 return true;
             }
         )
         .ToList();

// "john," "johnnxx" will also count as true
```